# How to pivot a pandas dataframe and calculate product of combinations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({
    'variable': ['gender','gender', 'age_group', 'age_group'],
    'category': ['F','M', 'Young', 'Old'],
    'value': [0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3],
})
variable    category    value
0   gender  F   0.6
1   gender  M   0.4
2   age_group   Young   0.7
3   age_group   Old 0.3
```

which represents my population. So in my population I have 60% Females, 70% Young etc.

I want to calculate the combinations of gender-age_group and output it in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'gender': ['F', 'F', 'M', 'M'],
    'age_group': ['Young', 'Old', 'Young', 'Old'],
    'percentage': [0.42, 0.18, 0.28, 0.12]
})

gender  age_group   percentage
0   F   Young   0.42
1   F   Old 0.18
2   M   Young   0.28
3   M   Old 0.12
```

which will show that the `Young Females` in the population are 42% (which comes from `0.6*0.7`), the `Old Males` are 12% (which comes from `0.4*0.3`) etc

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split by variable using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and compute the combinations with a cross-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
from functools import reduce

group = df.groupby('variable', sort=False)

out = reduce(lambda a,b: pd.merge(a, b, how='cross'),
             (g.rename(columns={'category': k})
               .drop(columns='variable')
              for k, g in group)
            )

out['percentage'] = (x:=out.filter(like='value')).prod(axis=1)
out = out.drop(columns=list(x))
```

Output:

```
  gender age_group  percentage
0      F     Young        0.42
1      F       Old        0.18
2      M     Young        0.28
3      M       Old        0.12
```

Example with more combinations:

```
# input
    variable category  value
0     gender        F   0.60
1     gender        M   0.40
2  age_group    Young   0.70
3  age_group      Old   0.30
4      other        a   0.45
5      other        b   0.55

# output
  gender age_group other  percentage
0      F     Young     a       0.189
1      F     Young     b       0.231
2      F       Old     a       0.081
3      F       Old     b       0.099
4      M     Young     a       0.126
5      M     Young     b       0.154
6      M       Old     a       0.054
7      M       Old     b       0.066
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
dfs = [df.rename(columns={'category':key}).drop('variable', axis=1) for key, df in df.groupby('variable', sort=False)]
out = pd.merge(*dfs, how='cross').assign(percentage=lambda x: x.pop('value_x').mul(x.pop('value_y')))
```

out:

```
    gender  age_group   percentage
0   F       Young       0.42
1   F       Old         0.18
2   M       Young       0.28
3   M       Old         0.12
```